# SQL comparing similar columns

Tags: sql, case, string-comparison

I have two columns that may contain similar data and I am trying to figure out how to compare both for similarities.

```
TABLE:
PatientID | InsurnaceCompany1 | InsuranceCompany2
111111111 | Medicaid          | Medicaid - Part D
222222222 | Medicaid - ABC Co | Medicaid
333333333 | Medicaid - ABC Co | Medicaid - Part D
444444444 | MVP Insurance     | MVP
555555555 | Medicare          | Medicaid
666666666 | Medicaid          | MVP
777777777 | Private - MVP     | MVP Option
```

Question is,
How do I compare the two columns to know if they are similar.

Results should be something like:

```
PatientID | InsurnaceCompany1 | InsuranceCompany2 | Result
111111111 | Medicaid          | Medicaid - Part D | TRUE
222222222 | Medicaid - ABC Co | Medicaid          | TRUE
333333333 | Medicaid - ABC Co | Medicaid - Part D | TRUE
444444444 | MVP Insurance     | MVP               | TRUE
555555555 | Medicare          | Medicaid          | FALSE
666666666 | Medicaid          | MVP               | FALSE
777777777 | Private - MVP     | MVP Option        | TRUE
```

I can use a case statement to check for several of these options like:

```
case
    when InsuranceCompany1 like '%' + InsuranceCompany2 + '%' then 'TRUE'
    when InsuranceCompany2 like '%' + InsuranceCompany1 + '%' then 'TRUE'
    else 'FALSE'
end AS Result
```

But this test fails for PatientID 333333333 and 777777777 above.

For clarification, I will define "similar" as the following:  The two terms are similar if they each contain the same word.  This applies even if the word is generic (such as "insurance") So "Insurance Company B" IS similar to "Insurance Company A" for two reasons: "Insurance" and "Company".

Comment: how do you define "similar"?

Comment: Similar would be if any part (word) of the first insurance company is in the second or vice versa.  Ie: if "medicaid" appears somewhere in both columns, then they are similar.  Likewise if "MVP" appears somewhere in both columns, then they are similar.

Comment: What if "insurance" appears in both columns?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do it without a stored procedure.

Comment: I would accept a TRUE answer if "insurance" appears in both.  Ideally it wouldn't, but for my use it would be acceptable.

Comment: You need to just write a stored procedure to break apart both columns, each value separated by a space, and then compare that.  I don't think you will find the answer in single case, like, or whatever (unless you have some very crazy logic in there).  You are going to have to process the data.  Unless - you want to look for certain, hard-coded strings.

Comment: You'll need to do a fuzzy match, which implies using Full-Text Search. This isn't solvable in a stored procedure without some help.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a lot of domain-specific knowledge (of what exactly constitutes "similar" names) implied in your question, and you're not going to be able to resolve this with a general-purpose comparison.  Your best option is probably to enumerate your specific requirements in your query, which will allow you to control exactly what you're getting:

```
select
  *
from
  patients
where
  InsuranceCompany1 like concat('%', InsuranceCompany2, '%') or 
  InsuranceCompany2 like concat('%', InsuranceCompany1, '%') or
  (InsuranceCompany1 like '%medicaid%' and InsuranceCompany2 like '%medicaid%') or
  (InsuranceCompany1 like '%medicare%' and InsuranceCompany2 like '%medicare%') or
  (InsuranceCompany1 like '%mvp%' and InsuranceCompany2 like '%mvp%') or
  ...etc...
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9de7b/13

Comment: That won't work, unfortunately, if something new comes up (say a new insurance company) as it will be hardcoded into the logic

Comment: No kidding, but the original requirement for "similarity" is so vague that it's the only practical way of addressing it.  You could cobble together a word-based parser that gives you a positive result when any word in one field matches any word in another field, but that's still going to fail when you get the patient that has "North Fairfield Insurance" and "South Fairfield Insurance".

Comment: I would consider "North Fairfield Insurance" and "South Fairfield Insurance" similar for both the fact that have "Farifield" and "insurance" in their name.

Comment: OK.  I guess I don't really see the point, though.  In any case, you're going to have a hard time with this, since SQL isn't particularly good at string parsing.  You can do some basic parsing with functions like locate() and substr(), but that is going to get ugly in a hurry for strings with variable numbers of words.  And I still think you're going to end up with a bunch of special-purpose logic, unless you're OK with the fact that your if-any-word-matches-then-they-are-similar logic is going to have "Medicaid - Part D" similar to "Joe Part & Sons Insurance".

Comment: You might also check out [this recent thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082990/how-can-i-separate-dynamic-data-different-lengths-with-a-substring) for some tips on the parsing.

Comment: Maybe it is best to think of this more generically:

`Table:`
`ID | FieldA | FieldB | HasCommonWord`

Answer (score -2):

**Edit**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (PatientID INT, InsurnaceCompany1 NVARCHAR(50), InsuranceCompany2 NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES 
(111111111,'Medicaid'          ,'Medicaid - Part D'),
(222222222,'Medicaid - ABC Co' ,'Medicaid'),
(333333333,'Medicaid - ABC Co'  ,'Medicaid - Part D'),
(444444444,'MVP Insurance'      ,'MVP'),
(555555555,'Medicare'           ,'Medicaid'),
(666666666,'Medicaid'           ,'MVP'),
(777777777,'Private - MVP'      ,'MVP Option')


SELECT PatientID, InsurnaceCompany1, InsuranceCompany2 ,
    CASE WHEN LEFT(InsurnaceCompany1,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', InsurnaceCompany1) = 0 
                    THEN LEN(InsurnaceCompany1) ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', InsurnaceCompany1) END ) 
            = LEFT(InsuranceCompany2,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', InsuranceCompany2) = 0 
                THEN LEN(InsuranceCompany2) ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', InsuranceCompany2) END ) 
                THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END    AS RESULT 
FROM @t
```

**Result Set**

```
PatientID   InsurnaceCompany1   InsuranceCompany2   RESULT
111111111   Medicaid            Medicaid - Part D   TRUE
222222222   Medicaid - ABC Co   Medicaid            TRUE
333333333   Medicaid - ABC Co   Medicaid - Part D   TRUE
444444444   MVP Insurance       MVP                 TRUE
555555555   Medicare            Medicaid            FALSE
666666666   Medicaid            MVP                 FALSE
777777777   Private - MVP       MVP Option          FALSE
```

Comment: I'm confused... isn't that saying either column can be anything?  `InsurnaceCompany1 like '%'`

Comment: InsuranceCompany1 like '%' + InsuranceCompany2 + '%' in question doesnt return True or False.

Comment: using AND or OR instead of + will actually yield True/False in WHEN Clause then user can return whatever is mentioned in THEN clause. In this case Strings 'True'or 'False'

Comment: By doing that, all the answers just equate to true.... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9c28/6/0  I don't think that is what OP wants...?

Comment: @user623952 have a look now but OP's term 'similar' is more of a Human term difficult to interoperate to T-Sql, needs to be more Precise what is 'similar'.

Comment: Its true, "similar" was too vague.  I defined it above, but post again here: Similar would be if any part (word) of the first insurance company is in the second or vice versa. Ie: if "medicaid" appears somewhere in both columns, then they are similar. Likewise if "MVP" appears somewhere in both columns, then they are similar.

Comment: @ajspacemanspiff I have tried giving somewhat 'similar' answer to the question which works but again there should be a Definition for the word SIMILAR what is considered Similar and what is not. but i guess my effort is in vain still got two down votes :)