# How can I separate dynamic data (different lengths) with a substring?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some assistance on separating data based on dynamic ranges with a start and end point.

For example, a string that looks like this:

```
N=Chris,,Lane,,M,,
N=Alen,,Smith,,E,,
```

N= is static and always the same. I can start a substring after the equals. The name on the other hand is dynamic and always changing in length, BUT there is a terminator with the commas. How do I select each segment of this column with SQL where Chris, Lane and M can be displayed in separate columns for First, Last and Middle name?

Comment: Why are you storing separate data points in a single column?

Comment: Who said I was storing it? If we could control how I data is stored and sent to us in every situation, then I think a lot of database guys would die from happiness. ;)

Comment: If you haven't stored it, then why are you using SQL to break it apart?

Comment: @Fastidious Any possibility of any segment coming empty like this `N=Chris,,,,M,,`?

Comment: @Aaron: Let me rephrase. I don't control how the data is sent to me. The point of this question is to break it apart and store it properly. In addition, before you ask, I rather keep the raw data in the original form and then break it apart and transform it the way I see fit. That from my understanding, is the correct way to handle situations like these because that process may change over time and I want to original state to always be well--original.

Comment: @mr_eclair: Yes, there is always a risk of data coming in with empty fields. It's not likely, and in this situation, it would be considered bad data. NULL's are put in by the application with blanks are left, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [this](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/03/17/Set-based-splitting-of-delimited-strings-to-columns.aspx) example

```
SELECT p.id, REPLACE(p.[1], 'N=', '') Col1, p.[2] Col2, p.[3] Col3, p.[4] Col4, p.[5] Col5, p.[6] Col6, p.[7] Col7
FROM (
  SELECT id, substring(d, start + 2, endPos - Start - 2) token, row_number() OVER (
      PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start
      ) n
  FROM (
    SELECT id, d, n start, charindex(',', d, n + 2) endPos
    FROM num
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT id, ',' + d + ',' d
      FROM @m
      ) m
    WHERE n < len(d) - 1
      AND substring(d, n + 1, 1) = ','
    ) d
  ) pvt
Pivot(max(token) FOR n IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) p
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/910d3/5)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for.... split function!!!  fn_split()

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496058(v=sql.80).aspx

```
CREATE  FUNCTION dbo.fn_Split(@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(    
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)   
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1 

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0) 

  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)  
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)  
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK  
      END 

    IF (@index >= 1)  
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))   
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))  
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
    END
  RETURN

END
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_Split('N=Chris,,,,,Lane,,M,,',',')
```

or you can pivot to your liking....

```
SELECT [1] AS FirstName,[2],[3] AS LastName,[4],[5] AS MiddleInitial,[6]
FROM (
    SELECT POSITION, VALUE 
    FROM dbo.fn_Split('N=Chris,,Lane,,M,,',',')
) p
PIVOT (MAX(VALUE) FOR POSITION IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) AS pvt
```

Didn't want to do all the work but the downvote upset me... I don't know why it feel so personal when I'm downvoted.... I need to work on that.  =(

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you can do parsing like this with `charindex` and `locate`:

```
select
  substring(text, 3, charindex(',', text) - 3) firstName,
  substring(text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text) + 1) + 1, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text) + 1) + 1) - charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text) + 1) - 1) lastName, 
  substring(text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) - charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text, charindex(',', text) + 1) + 1) + 1) - 1) middleName,
from
  t
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/421b5/25)